# Using something similar to \n rather than empty WriteLn() in free pascal

Tags: freepascal

```
procedure A();
//Do something useful    
WriteLn('This is a message');

procedure B();
//Do something else useful
WriteLn();                 //<---Empty WriteLn();
WriteLn('This is another message');

procedure C();
//Do something else useful
A();
B();
WriteLn();                 //<---Empty WriteLn();
WriteLn('This is another message from C');
```

This is only 3 procedures, and my program has more than 3 procedures like this...Is there a way that I don't have to put empty WriteLn(); (something like \n in html) in most procedures because of aesthetic reasons?

Thanks!

Comment: `Write(#13#10);` writes a CR + LF sequence. If you want an extra new line: `WriteLn('Give me more space'#13#10);`

Comment: And if you want to start with a new line:`WriteLn(#13#10'Start with a new line');`

Comment: Thanks for the comments, it's exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper way to do this is actually to use an empty `Writeln`. A second best, also platform-independent way is to use something like:

```
Writeln(sLineBreak + sLineBreak + 'This is another message');
```

*(`sLineBreak` is defined in unit `System`, AFAIK).*

But if you already think that using an empty `Writeln` is too much, then you can insert the carriage return and line feed characters in the string, as below:

#### Windows

Just add a carriage return (`#13`) /line feed (`#10`) combination:

```
procedure B();
begin
  //Do something else useful
  WriteLn(#13#10'This is another message');
end;
```

You can even have multiple empty lines like that:

```
  Writeln(#13#10#13#10'Hello');
  Writeln('-----'#13#10#13#10);
```

#### Non-Windows

If you are on a non-Windows platform, probably a `#10` (line feed) will do. Most non-Windows platforms do not need the carriage return.

---

*FWIW, instead of `#10` you can also use `^J` and instead of `#13` you can use `^M`. These are equivalents:*

```
  Writeln(^M^J^M^J'Hello');
  Writeln('-----'^M^J^M^J);
```

*`^M` is Ctrl+M, which has ASCII code 77 - 64 = 13! `^J` is 74 - 64 = 10.*

Comment: Surely this is what sLineBreak is for

Comment: @David: yes, but that is a string and you must concatenate it. I personally prefer `'x'#13#10'y'` instead of `'x' + sLineBreak + 'y'`. And I didn't look if FreePascal has an `SLineBreak`. But the `SLineBreak` would probably be platform-dependent.

Comment: Your code is platform dependent. Using sLineBreak would be platform independent.

Comment: @David: yes, you are right. And that is actually what I meant: dependent on the platform, it would be different.

Comment: @David: but if using an extra call to Writeln is already too much (which is what I would do), I guess using SLineBreak would not be acceptable either. <g>

Comment: @David: changed it a little, for general use. But ISTM that asker was after what I already had.